# Surah 3:65-3:67

Tags: quran

Someone was talking about Surah 3:65-3:67 and he says how the Quran be the word if god if allah that why do the Christian’s and Jews dispute about Abraham even though their scriptures came after his time. he says that Quran is also after Abraham’s time so how can he say that even though the Quran is after Abraham?, he says that argument is so dumb that the Quran cannot be from god

Comment: Assalam, your english is not well understandable. But Christians a well as Jews don't dispute Abraham.

Comment: I meant that the Quran invalidates other religions that claim that they follow Abraham or he is Jewish or Christian because they’re books came after a Abraham even though the Quran also came after Abraham

Comment: Abraham cannot be Christian, simply because Jesus was born long after him. Obviously, Abraham was of Jewish origin, like it or not. Do you know about Ismail?

Comment: Yes but wouldn’t that also apply to the Quran ?

Comment: Like that Abraham can’t be a Muslim because the Quran came after him

Comment: I don't know. Maybe Abraham was aware of the Quran, that preexisted even before the Prophet Muhammad was told. This discussion is getting way out of what I know, or even think to know, about Islam. Please wait for other more Islam based answers.

Comment: no, no, no, you are confusing the *revelation* of the Quran with the *Quran* as have ever been..

Comment: Ok thanks for the help anyways

Comment: please continue to ask and try to sharpen your question.

Comment: Yes  jazakallah khair